# Change the default Bookmarks Folder In Firefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

The default bookmarks folder in Firefox is **Other Bookmarks**.
Is is possible to change it to **Bookmarks Toolbar**? (If possible without add-ons).
I am using Firefox 68.0.2 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: No it's not ... the only option is to drag and drop. a discussion is going on for 2 years: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1432604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bookmarks Toolbar option is inbuilt into 68.02.2 (64 bit).

[image]

If it's not already visible on your system you need to perform the following steps (which don't involve add-ons).

Press <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> to get the menu bar [File Edit View etc] at the top of the FireFox menu bar.

Then select `view→Toolbars→Bookmarks Toolbar` and ensure that there is a ✓ next to `Bookmarks Toolbar`.

You can the drag and drop pages as required either directly on to the Bookmarks Toolbar or down in to the Bookmarks option in the sidebar (you may need to ensure that `view→Sidebar→Bookmarks` is also showing a ✔

Comment: Although this does not answer my question but it is a good work around, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no possible way to change the default bookmarks folder without add-ons, I found myself obliged to use one ([Default Bookmark Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/default-bookmark-folder/)).
By using this add-on, it is possible to change the default bookmarks folder to any other folder (**Bookmarks Toolbar** in my case).

[image]

It even has a **quick bookmarking** feature.

> This feature will add a quick bookmark icon in the address bar, to
>   (un)bookmark a page with only one click. The icon is a round star icon
>   in the address bar. If the current page is bookmarked, the icon color
>   will change to the selected color (red by default). Here is a
>   screenshot to serve as examples: when the current page is not
>   bookmarked and when it is.

[image]